# MFMailComposeViewController losing attachments after sending

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a head scratcher, i have created a UITableView to display recorded data stored in the documents directory which then allows me to select multiple files and send them in an email.
This works great, i select the listed files i want to send in my email, click the email button and an email will appear with a list of attached files. The names and extensions are correct.

The problem is, i then send the email and once it is received the attachments have dissapeared and been replaced with txt files with names such as ATT00001.txt, ATT00002.txt and so on.

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening and how it can be fixed? i have listed my code below:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [filePathsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.csv'"];
    NSArray *csvFiles = [fileList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
    NSLog(@"Contents of directory: %@", csvFiles);
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [csvFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

# pragma mark - Deleting data from Row.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    {
        NSString *fileName = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *path;
        NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSError *error;
        [filePathsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadData];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Delete file error:%@", error);
            }
            NSLog(@"Deleting file named: %@", path);
        }

    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedData addObject:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] count];
        [self updateEmailButtonTitle];
        NSLog(@"selectedData %@",self.selectedData);

    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedData removeObject:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self updateEmailButtonTitle];
        NSLog(@"deselectedData %@",self.selectedData);
    }

}

#pragma mark - Email Selected Data

-(IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender
{
    [self showEmail];

}

- (void)showEmail {

    NSString *emailTitle = @"Your Data";
    NSString *messageBody = @"Attached is your recorded data.";

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];

    for (NSString *file in self.selectedData) {

        // Determine the file name
        NSString *filename = [self.selectedData objectAtIndex:0];

        // Read the file using NSData

        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

        // Add attachment
        [mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:filename];
    }

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - here is the finished and working code, thank you to everyone who helped with this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [filePathsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.csv'"];
    NSArray *csvFiles = [fileList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
    NSLog(@"Contents of directory: %@", csvFiles);
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [csvFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

# pragma mark - Deleting data from Row.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    {
        NSString *fileName = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *path;
        NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSError *error;
        [filePathsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadData];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Delete file error:%@", error);
            }
            NSLog(@"Deleting file named: %@", path);
        }

    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedData addObject:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] count];
        [self updateEmailButtonTitle];
        NSLog(@"selectedData %@",self.selectedData);

    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedData removeObject:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self updateEmailButtonTitle];
        NSLog(@"deselectedData %@",self.selectedData);
    }

}


-(void)updateEmailButtonTitle
{

    NSArray *selectedRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];


    if (selectedRows.count == self.selectedData.count)
    {
        self.emailButton.enabled = NO;
        self.emailButton.title = @"Email";

    } else if (selectedRows.count == 0) {
        self.emailButton.enabled = YES;
        self.emailButton.title = @"Email Selected Data";
    }
}

#pragma mark - Email Selected Data

-(IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender
{
    [self showEmail];

}

- (void)showEmail
{

    NSString *emailTitle = @"Your Data";
    NSString *messageBody = @"Attached is your recorded data.";

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];

    for (NSString *file in self.selectedData) {

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *csvFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]; // This will check the conents of the string "file" and match it with files located in the documents directory.
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:csvFilePath];

        NSLog(@"my nsdata is %@",myData);  //check whether your nsdata is nil or not

        [mc addAttachmentData:myData
                                     mimeType:@"text/csv"
                                     fileName:file];

        }

        [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];


    }



- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Does ATT00001.txt contain any data? Data in the txt doc is correct as you saved?

Comment: @Vidhyanand unfortunatly not, they are blank files.

Comment: simple. The csv files are not attaching to your email. you can see the icon of csv file attaching to email but in reality no csv file is attached to the email.

Comment: Post your nsdata and check whether csv file exists in the path

Comment: There is an issue with your email attachment code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code attached the csv file properly  for me:

```
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *csvFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]; //This checkes the string "file" for a list of selected files which can then be matched up to the contents of the documents directory.
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:csvFilePath];

    NSLog(@"my nsdata is %@",myData);  //check whether your nsdata is nil or not

    [mc addAttachmentData:myData
                                 mimeType:@"text/csv"
                                 fileName:file];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and let you know how I get on. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Thanks, this very nearly worked but wasnt quite right, i have edited your answer to show the finished working answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change one line of code..

// Read the file using NSData

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

//To

```
NSData *fileData = [file dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

// also specify the fileName as per format..

// Add attachment

```
NSString* fileNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv", filename];//fileName should be only name not entire path.

[mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:fileNameStr];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: Hi @Vidhyanand, thank you for the above, it did fix the attachment issue however it revealed another issue, the attachment did not contain the data stored within the documents directory that i had selected but instead created a CSV file with the name of the file in the documents directory in the first field. Are you able to see from the code where i have gone wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You have send an attachment with mimeType:@"text/csv" . So due to this reason when you received the data . It will always be in text format.So change the format of file that you are sending .But You are sending your whole file along with the extision in FILENAME parameter . So You have to seperate the filename from the extionsion .And then you send it.